# Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'fs'

Tags: typescript, webpack, fs-extra

I'm getting this error:

```
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'fs'
```

in `main` :

```
import fs from 'fs-extra'

fs.ensureDir(settingsUserDataFolder, err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

If I comment this part:

```
//fs.ensureDir(settingsUserDataFolder, err => {
  //console.log(err)
//})
```

the error disappears

In `webpack.main.config.js` :

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')

module.exports = {
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstypecommonjs
  externalsType: 'commonjs',
  externals: {
    'fs': 'fs-extra',
  }
};
```

`ts.config.json` :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 16",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es2021", "dom", "dom.iterable"], // https://www.e-learn.cn/topic/3468143
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Other Info:

```
"typescript": "^4.9.3",
"electron": "^17.2.0",
"@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.63",
"@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
 "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",

node: v18.12.1
O.S.: Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
```

With `import fsExtra from 'fs-extra'` I get the same error:

```
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'fsExtra'
```

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Don't reuse the name. `import fsExtra from 'fs-extra'`

Comment: Hi @Quentin ! Thanks for helping. I imported `fs-extra` in this way: `import fs from 'fs-extra'` : Is it correct, or if wrong, how to correctly import `fs-extra` ?

Comment: I literally gave you the revised code in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry @Quentin . With `import fsExtra from 'fs-extra'` I get the same error:

`Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'fsExtra'` ( I updated my post above)

Comment: @Quentin based on here: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#commonjs we could use both `import fs from 'fs-extra'` and `import fse/fsExtra from 'fs-extra'`